# Batch Variable name and Percent sign

Tags: variables, batch-file, environment-variables, scope

I have a variable named ABC

```
SET ABC=Brazil
```

I have another variable named DEF containing a string with the name of the first variable:

```
SET "DEF=%%ABC%%"
```

How can I access to the string "Brazil" by only using the variable *DEF*? (I can't use the variable *ABC*)

If I use the Echo command it (correctly) shows *%ABC%*.

```
ECHO %DEF% ------> %ABC%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call echo %DEF%
```

When the line is found, the parser executes variable substitution generating

```
call echo %ABC%
```

Now, the command is executed, and the `call` generates a second parser pass that will resolve the new generated variable reference